# Why can't have multiple [fromUrl] tags in asp.net web api route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My HttpConfiguration code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByToken",
    routeTemplate: "web_api/{controller}/{action}/{token}",
    defaults: new { token = RouteParameter.Optional}
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "web_api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And I have an api and it is used for login :

```
[HttpPost]
public string Login([FromUri]string token, [FromBody]string user, [FromBody] string pwd)
{
    //...
}
```

What bothers me is that if I code like that, there will be an exception saying that I can't bind multiple variables(user and pwd) to the request when I send a request.

But if I remove one of the [fromBody] tags, it will be ok:

```
public string Login([FromUri]string token, [FromBody]string user)
public string Login([FromUri]string token, [FromBody] string pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So this will not work:

```
// Caution: Will not work!    
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

[explanation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)